# org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, jboss

Why am I getting the below exception in my application when it is trying to pass an array of strings to a stored procedure from java code?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:160)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:128)
```

I am getting the exception in the line below:

```
          **ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("REQ_TYPE_ARRAY", connection);**
```

I am using JDK 6, JBOSS EAP 6.1, Oracle 11g, OJDBC 11.2.0.2.0 jar, spring 2.5

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a conflict in the odbc jar version in your classpath.. probably one that spring includes with the one in jboss...

Comment: Thanks for reply.There is no ojdbc jar directly deployed in my application ear file.                                              I put the ojdbc-11.2.0.2.0 jar in <JBOSS_HOME>/jboss-eap-6.1/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main and and in my ear file, i put the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file which is containing the path to ojdbc11.

Comment: Thanks Mark for reply. I have already tried with unwrap() with the below line. It is not working.                                                   OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );

Comment: @user3278849 See the accepted answer on that question; there might be two different drivers loaded.